# Typescript forward generic type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

consider this type and this generic:

```js
type Data = { item: number };

type Generic<T> = {
  obj: T;
};
```

now this is an instance of it:

```js
const test: Generic<Data> = { obj: { item: 0 } };
```

now what I really need when using `test.obj` is to see the type for obj (`Data`) when clicking on it, not it's type in the Generic (`T`)

### When clicking on `test.obj`

[image]

#### What I expected:

to go to `Data` type definition

```js
type Data = { item: number };
```

#### What happend:

it went to its definition in the generic `T`

```js
type Generic<T> = {
  obj: T;
};
```

so is this possible?

Comment: in the image you posted it shows that the (property) `obj` is of type `Data`

Comment: Is this an IntelliSense question?  What do you mean by "clicking" and "it went to its definition" exactly?  Presumably this is some IDE behavior?  Maybe this question should be given some IDE-related tags?

Comment: @jcalz sorry I should have versed it better, I don't want to see here that it's a generic T because it's useless information (in my case), so I just needed the generic to create rules (there should be a property obj with type T) but when using it I don't want to see the generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.obj` isn't a type: it's a property. When you use "Go to Definition" on that symbol, it'll show you the `obj` property, which is defined by the generic type.

Check to see if your IDE has a "Go to Type Definition" option instead. This will take you to the type of the symbol you have highlighted, rather than the symbol itself:

[image: Choose Go to Type Definition]

[image: result]